# Duplicate Primary Key with Composite Key on inserting data

Tags: mysql, duplicates, composite-primary-key, load-data-infile

I have a table that I just created and the primary key is the a composite key of the first two columns (HostID, IPAddress). When I try to use LOAD Data INFILE to fill the table from a CSV, it tells me there is a duplicate primary key error. I can guarantee that each composite key is unique. What is happening here? Is it only taking the first column as a PK or is it a problem with the insert of data? I'm working in mySQL within mSQL. Error message: "Duplicate entry '0-' for key 'PRIMARY'"

This is the LOAD DATA INFILE CODE which works everytime I use it but now.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/admmathew.gake/Documents/VIM_hosts.csv'
INTO TABLE vim_hosts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

This is the CREATE query

```
CREATE TABLE VIM_Hosts (
    HostID INT(5) NOT NULL,
    IPAddresses VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    NodeID INT(5) NULL,
    DataCenterID INT(5) NULL,
    ManageObjectID VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    HostName VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    HostStatus INT(5) NULL,
    Model VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Vendor VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    OverallStatus VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    NetworkUtilization FLOAT(20,15) NULL,
    NetworkTransmitRate FLOAT(20,10) NULL,
    NetworkRecieveRate FLOAT(20,10) NULL,
    CPULoad FLOAT(20,10) NULL,
    CPUUsageMHz INT(10) NULL,
    MemUsage FLOAT(20,10) NULL,
    MemUsageMB INT(15) NULL,
    VMCount INT(5) NULL,
    VMRunningCount INT(5) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (HostID, IPAddresses)
);
```

Comment: you need to specify the primary key as auto increment

Comment: Its not an autoincrement. It has a set number of values but they repeat occasionally so I combined it with IP Address as a composite

Comment: Looks like there are either two rows with empty values for the first two fields or there is something else in your csv which MySQL reads as a row but you don't.

Comment: Just checked the CSV and there are no 0 values in the data but there was some blank space at the bottom, would this cause the problem? @Vatev

Comment: i think its because of the blank space that you noted there ^

Comment: @BenHowells I don't know, but its worth a try

Comment: Unfortunately I tried it and it did not fix my problem. It wasn't the blank space

Comment: Can you load the file in portions to try & determine the offending line?

Comment: Post some sample lines from the .csv file in the question section

Comment: I've the same issue, in my case there are two columns defining the Composite-PK (`start`, `end` both *varchars*) and are unique in the CSV file. The targeted table has no *auto-increment* on the PKs and none of my data in CSV would cause in a *null* value, so I'm really confused how this could happen. My first idea was that the Composite-PK maybe just accepts the length of one key and so I increased the varchar length from 10 to 16. (so it would fit the length of the longest composite key) but this still hasn't helped. **:(**